# Compile C++ for all linux distributions

Tags: c++, linux

How can i compile my C++ files to work on ALL linux distributions.
The machine that i'll compile them on is Ubuntu 10.10

If i compile them on Ubuntu 10.10, will they work on other Distros like ubuntu, fedora, debian, non debian distros.. etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
% gcc -o foo foo.c -static
```

the resulting binary should work on most distros, given that it runs on the same architecture (64bit, 32bit, arm, mips etc).

the main point is: since you do not know what can be found on the target systems in advance, you have to bundle everything you can into either the binary you are shipping or in some kind of "chrooted" environment where you deploy external libs as well (stuff that can't be linked statically) and then have some kind of a wrapper to use your deployed libs instead of the system libs.

Comment: That will work for C, but not C++. See http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/

Answer (score 4):

Although @akira answer will probably work for your case, it isn't the best solution. Most Linux distros have packing systems which retrieve the dependencies for you.

If you are serious about writing Linux software which is used on other people's boxes, you will need to look into 'GNU Autotools' which is what drives the ' ./configure && make all && make install ' thing which you will have run more than once by now!

Comment: Umm, the project is not open source?

Comment: @Daniel you would still be better off using Autotools yourself, even if you are not giving the code away for free! Otherwise you will make your life difficult when the libraries your code depends on change, but like I said @akira idea will most likely do what you want.

Comment: If his project requires Autotools, which is under the GPL, even if it is just to build his software prior to distribution, is it legal for his own software to be under a GPL-incompatible license? (This is an earnest question, not GPL flamebait.)

Comment: If you are distributing just the binaries, Yes of course it is legal. The GPL covers 'derivative works' which is taken to mean 'cut and pasting' the source code to make something new, not using a tool to help you do something else. In the same way using Word doesn't give Microsoft copyright on your novel.

Answer (score 2):

It is much harder than it should be, at least for C++: http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/

Answer (score 1):

Provided you only use the libraries listed in the Linux Standards Base, a dynamic executable should be fine.

For other libraries, either link with static versions of them, or ship dynamic libraries; I prefer the former.

I would personally recommend avoiding static-linking the C library, as this prevents some useful functionality provided by it working, for example the nss stuff..